# How to handle nested each with input type in Jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I tried to look after a similar problem but couldn't find any here. So here is my problem. I have a structure with multiple div. Each div have a class name 'testClass'. I need to fetch the attributes of all input types, button
Here is my code,

```
<body>

<div class="testClass">
    /* Few Code */
    <input type="text" id="txt1" /> <br/>   <input type="text" id="txt21" />
    /* Few Code */
    <button id="btn1">Button1</button>  
</div>

<div class="testClass">
    /* Few Code */
    <input type="text" id="txt2" /> <br/>   <input type="text" id="txt22" />
    /* Few Code */
    <button id="btn2">Button2</button>  
</div>

<div class="testClass">
    /* Few Code */
    <input type="text" id="txt3" /> <br/>   <input type="text" id="txt23" />
    /* Few Code */
    <button id="btn3">Button3</button>  
</div>
```

I have tried following

```
$("div .testClass").each(function() {

/* Some code present */

      $(this).find('input,button').each(function(){

      });
});
```

but it is not working. How can i select input types from div class testClass after the first each statement.

Could you help? Thanks.

Comment: which attributes do you need?  All of them, or just the `type` attribute?

Comment: Remove the space from your selector `"div .testClass"`, that is, use `"div.testClass"`. Your way you're looking for elements with that class that are descendants of divs, not divs with that class.

Comment: The extra dot after the second `each` is also present in your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("div.testClass").find(":input").each(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr('type');
    // Do something with the returned type
});
```

If you just need the buttons, set the find value to ':button'

Comment: Thanks. Will it possible in following code,<br/> $("div .testClass").each(function() { /* Few code */
      $(this).find('input,button').each.(function(){

      });
});

Comment: That would find all divs with class 'testClass' and then search all inputs within those divs. Make sure there's no space between div and .testClass, just div.testClass

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
$("div.testClass :input").each(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr('type');
});
```